# How I can dynamically load a template through a menu on a single method for all the menu. JSF 2, Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How I can dynamically load a template through a menu on a single method for all the menu. How I can identify the menu item that invoked the method.
this is my xhtml:

```
 <h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="80" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form id="form3">  
                    <ui:include src="./templates/template.xhtml" />  
                </h:form> 
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" header="Opciones" size="175">
                <h:form id="form1">
                    <p:panelMenu style="width:200px">   
                        <p:submenu label="Clientes" >
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateAddCliente}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Modificar" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateConfigCliente}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Listado" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateListadoCliente}" />
                        </p:submenu> 
                        <p:submenu label="Contratos">  
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateAddContrato}" />
                        </p:submenu>  
                        <p:separator/>  
                        <p:submenu label="Suplementos" >  
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" icon="ui-icon-signal"/>  
                        </p:submenu>  
                    </p:panelMenu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerlayout">
                <h:form id="form2">  
                    <ui:include src="#{templateMB.centerTemplate}" />  
                </h:form> 
                <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Subir Documento del Contrato" resizable="false" widgetVar="fileDialog" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" width="500" height="200"> 

                    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                        <p:panel id="panelDialog">
                            <p:fileUpload value="#{contratosMB.fileContrato}" mode="simple" style="width: 400px"/>  
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <p:commandButton value="Guardar" ajax="false"  
                                             actionListener="#{contratosMB.upload}"/>  
                        </p:panel>
                    </h:form>  

                </p:dialog> 
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>
```

This is my backing bean:

```
      public String templateAddCliente() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/addCliente.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

  public String templateConfigCliente() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/configCliente.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
  public String templateHome() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/hometemplate.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

  public String templateListadoCliente() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/listadoCliente.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

  public String templateAddContrato() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/addContratos.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

so far everything works fine, but I have to create a method for each menu item and I do not like. I want to use a single method in backinbean to load pages and can not find the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that with JSF 2 you are able to handle parameters in your action methods (Not related to JSF per se, but to the EL implementation).

You can use an enumeration, a numeric type or a `String` to define the actual tempalte to display. The simplest example would be a method (let's call it `displayTemplate`) that receives a `String` defining the template you want to show.

```
public displayTemplate(String templateId) {
    centerTemplate = templateMap.get(templateId);
}
```

As an idea, you can register your templates in a `Map` that contains the path as a value and the `templateId` as a key, to easily switch between templates. Just remember to initialize this map.

```
Map<String,String> templateMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
//...
templateMap.put("addCliente","./templates/addCliente.xhtml");
//The very same with the other templates
```

Finally, in your page you can invoke the method like this:

```
<p:menuitem value="Adicionar" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.displayTemplate('addCliente')}" />
```

Comment: hi, thank but waht can I do if the menu dynamically generated it¿?

Comment: If the template is dynamically generated by the menu then you'll have no choice but to switch over the different possibilities and return the value (either by the use of conditional statements or by an int/char/enum switch statement or with a string if you're on Java 7). If there's any chance for you to preprocess the templates I suggest you do it, otherwise do it on demand.